# Prove the randomness of elements in list

Tags: statistics, random-variables, random, correlation

I wrote a function that generates random numbers (but not with libraries) I could use `numpy` or `statistic` library in python, But generate them from scratch.

Now I have a list of numbers, But the problem is how can I show that these numbers are actually random? I am familiar with the concept of correlation but don't know how to use it for my problem or is there any other mathematical way or library to prove this?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a function that is truly random. So you're not going to be able to, because your function *isn't* random.

Comment: I mean it's not perfectly random, it's a pseudo-random generator. Anyway, I want to see how much random are these numbers.

Comment: I've got no idea about such things. But you might also want to ask this on cross-validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is not possible to prove a sequence to be random. If it passes several well designed random tests it is probably a random sequence. Such tests should be available online.

Comment: There are many ways in which to show that data (or the procedure that generated them) are _not_ random. But there is no way to be absolutely sure of randomness. // If I generate 100 data points in R using `z = rnorm(100)`. then for `x=1:100` taking `cor(z,x)` should ordinarily give a correlation not far from $0,$ very rarely near $-1$ or $1.$ Just did it several times in R: results $=0.16, 0.11, -.01, .09.$ Nothing suspicious there.// Chi-squared tests, and runs tests also often used.

Comment: If you google "testing random number generators" you will get many hits.